# pip install paho-mqtt traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python, pip, sudo, paho

I have a problem to ask regarding paho-mqtt. Whenever i tried to install

```
sudo pip install paho-mqtt
```

It would come out something like this

```
Collecting paho-mqtt

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 350, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 837, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 323, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 308, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_verify_locations(ca_certs, ca_cert_dir)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 392, in load_verify_locations
    self._ctx.load_verify_locations(cafile, capath)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 525, in load_verify_locations
    _raise_current_error()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 48, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
Error: []
```

I tried this method

```
cd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

sudo ln -s /home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paho
```

But it still shows the same problem. This problem have been occuring for a long time and i did alot of research using various solution but the problem still remain the same. Apparently, anything regarding to pip installation i would face the traceback problem. I really need some help regarding this. Thank you!

Comment: You should post the full traceback. The most important part at the end is missing.

Comment: I wanted to but stackoverflow doesnt allow me to it says my post contain too much code then doesn't allow me to post

Answer (score 1):

I manage to solve the problem which is there is something went wrong with my OS installation, i was using NOOBS previously and now i tried to install the OS of "Raspbian Stretch with desktop" and now it is working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error in previous days.
You should try this before installing `paho-mqtt`.

`pip install --upgrade setuptools`

please let me know if its work or not!

for more information, Go to [Onion Docs](https://docs.onion.io/omega2-docs/installing-and-using-python.html#fixing-the-setup-tools-issue)

Comment: Apparently it was my OS that has problem as all install that is related to pip there's traceback problem which after reinstalling it is now working. Thanks for the help anyway!